# Visual Studio C++/CLI Mysterious Error With Template

Tags: c#, c++, .net, dll, visual-studio-2015

Well, I've been trying to make a C++ DLL in Visual Studio 2015, which took a while since I'm not very good with Visual Studio.

I need to access the .NET libraries, specifically System::Management. (Writing the code was a little harder than it needed to be due to a poor C++ implementation, but at least it has one.)

I fixed obvious errors and finally figured out I had to enable CLR in the project properties and then select the related libraries with References->Add Reference. But after all that, now it's just giving this weird error:

```
LNK1104: cannot open file 'MSCOREE.lib'
```

The compiler doesn't show red wavy lines below anything, and the error claims the line is "1" and the file is "LINK", so no help there.

I thought I probably messed up the project configuration somewhere, so I created a new project and moved the code over. The error still happened. If I turned off CLR and commented out the .NET-dependent code, the build succeeded without errors.

So I tried creating a new project from template (Visual C++ -> Win32 Console Application) and then enabling CLR before doing anything else. Then I tried again, selecting different versions of .NET framework.

Finally, I tried creating a project with template (Visual C++ -> CLR -> CLR Console Application) and building it immediately. I mean literally without doing ANYTHING ELSE. It still gave the same error!

```
LNK1104: cannot open file 'MSCOREE.lib'
```

What on earth is going on? Am I doing something wrong here, or is VS2015 just broken?

Answer (score 14):

I had the same problem. **Installing ".NET Framework 4.6.1 SDK"** solved the problem. Pay attention to the version number, take it from your project configuration files

Comment: Worked for me. For those who use Chocolaty, the component name is "Microsoft.Net.ComponentGroup.4.6.1.DeveloperTools". Got it from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/workload-component-id-vs-build-tools?view=vs-2019#net-desktop-build-tools)

Comment: I use VS2019 + vc141 and I had exactly the same problem. I saw this answer but did not pay attention that it has to be **SDK**. Also I had .NET Framework 4.8 installed and thought it is enough. But it is not :).. So yeah, .NET Framework 4.6.1 SDK is essential for vc141 toolset

Comment: @DmytroOvdiienko, 4.8 SDK does fully replace 4.6.1 so you don't have to install it. It's enough to set environment variable `NETFXKitsDir`  that points to "C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.8\" folder.

Answer (score 8):

Check in Visual Studio installer 'C++/CLI support' for build tools of your needed version.

Comment: How do I know which version of C++/CLI support I need? I see multiple versions in VS2019.

Comment: @VinShahrdar the version is specified in .sln/.proj

Answer (score 2):

Try this,
Right click the project that shows 'LNK1104: cannot open file 'MSCOREE.lib'',  then select Properties --> Configuration Properties --> VC++ Directories --> Library Directories --> Add both entries from below separated by semi-colon

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1A\Lib
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1A\Lib\x64
```

This is where your 'mscoree.lib' should be, check if its there before doing this otherwise you might need to install/reinstall the Microsoft SDKs

Comment: Dose Windows SDK 10 have the same installation? I cannot find this file in my Windows SDK 10 installation. :-( Still investigating but not sure this one is reused by a higher version SDK (10)

Answer (score 1):

In some situations the SDK may not install the required files in the LIB folder as described in [MSCoree.lib missing from WinSDK](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/karinm/2008/12/14/mscoree-lib-missing-from-winsdk-install/). Their solution was to execute a repair of the install. That may not work.

I have successfully ran `WinSDKInterop_amd64\WinSDKInterop_amd64.msi` resulting in the creation of:

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1\Lib\IA64\mscoree.lib
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1\Lib\mscoree.lib
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1\Lib\x64\mscoree.lib
```