# Attempting to print SerialPort inputs to the console

Tags: c++-cli, visual-studio-2019

First my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#using <System.dll>

using namespace System;
using namespace System::IO::Ports;
using namespace System::Threading;

int main()
{
    SerialPort^ mySerialPort = gcnew SerialPort("COM5");
    mySerialPort->BaudRate = 9600;
    mySerialPort->Parity = Parity::None;
    mySerialPort->StopBits = StopBits::One;
    mySerialPort->DataBits = 8;
    mySerialPort->Handshake = Handshake::None;
    mySerialPort->RtsEnable = true;

    while (1)
    {
        Console::WriteLine(Console::ReadLine());
    }
}
```

The idea was to read from the SerialPort and write to the console. [Source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.ports.serialport)

Originally I was going to use:

```
std::cout << Console::ReadLine() << '\n';
```

However, that had an error (ReadLine outputs String^ not String, I don't know the difference) and I was hoping for something to compile.

With the above code I received the error:
two-phase name lookup is not supported for C++/CLI ... use /Zc:twoPhase-

The error recommends I use /Zc:twoPhase- which is a [compiler option](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/zc-twophase). So I enabled it and got the error:
Element   has an invalid value of "Yes(/permissive-) /Zc:twoPhase-"

I'm not quite sure how to proceed from here.

Apologies I'm a beginner and I dove way over my head. Any help would be appreciated!
Note: I included thread, I know this code doesn't use it, but I plan on using it later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Judging by the "Element has an invalid value of "Yes(/permissive-) /Zc:twoPhase-"" you've put this compiler option where it does not belong. Make sure you know where it should go. E.g. [Why do I have warning "C4199 two-phase name lookup is not supported for C++/CLI, C++/CX, or openmp"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56782470/why-do-i-have-warning-c4199-two-phase-name-lookup-is-not-supported-for-c-cli)

Comment: I tried that. I solved on error and gave me a new one. "cannot open file "MSCOREE.lib".

Comment: @SaltyRusnPotato I looked it up and it looks like a problem with .NET Framework SDK. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41030806/visual-studio-c-cli-mysterious-error-with-template/56440592)

Answer (score 0):

There is no solution. I got an "cannot open file 'MSCOREE.lib'" error. It appears that file no longer exists in Windows and I didn't know how to get ahold of it. So I used the Visual Studio [Windows Form App](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dnmJ-OjAh38&t=131s).

Edit: eXCore's comment about the .NET framework solved it.